# Parse Json data into simple array Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json

I got the following json array in the ajax call like this

```
item    restaurants
places  [{"geometry":{"location":{"H":31.485241,"L":74.30220800000006}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles
/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png","id":"f8d9edcb5068bcd868e225429e881a351a5e2795","name":"Subway","opening_hours"
:{"open_now":true,"weekday_text":[]},"photos":[{"height":720,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https:/
/maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116044146831530051317\">Adnan Fayyaz</a>"],"width":960}],"place_id":"ChIJpaImhvEDGTkRw35DXlvUTIE"
,"price_level":1,"rating":2.9,"reference":"CmRaAAAAr8mbHo-J1Wq8YTjzyiHRmwMkh40-26VJ6WqBxgjdAtT4v2HuT
Lb_OEYS7DUqHHIOe__ywd7S0E8oWgarwGD-DdlS1SVmrEo_Sl58o3PO528LAPGBSuN8luGTXLkKS0waEhCBQcGYE1ejtMRrY1F6zK5NGhTuIi9f4ht2CC0obNOpChdD1P_8yA"
,"scope":"GOOGLE","types":["restaurant","food","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"A Block
, Lahore","html_attributions":[]}]
```

Now when i do `p params["item"]` in the console it gives me 'restaurants' (correct) when i do `p params["places"]` it gives me the whole response (which is again correct) but when i try to get (let's say) first geometry thing by typing `p params['places'][0]` it gives me just two brackets like

> [ 
>  [

and nothing else is shown . while my expecting result is first element in the array which is geometry thing . also p params['places'][0].geometry gives nil , why ? what am i missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p params['places'][0]` is printing brackets because `params['places']` is a string. You are then printing the first character of the string.

To get the content of the JSON, you first need to parse it, with for example the `json` gem.

```
require json
places = JSON.parse(params['places'])
p places[0]
```